# How do I get NSString values from an Mutable Object Array?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm at the point in my app where I need to replace the image of a sprite and I think I know  how to do it, but I'm having trouble implementing it. Basically, I'm making a domino game and I need to be able to flip the domino over so you can see the numbers.

Starting with my domino.h file....

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Domino : CCSprite {
    int int_leading;
    int int_trailing;
    int int_suitrank;
    int int_playerid;

    NSString *str_tilename;
    NSString *str_mirrortilename;    
}


@property  int int_leading,int_trailing, int_playerid, 

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str_tilename;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *str_mirrortilename;

-(void) print;
-(void) setTileName: (NSString *) theTileName;
-(void) setMirrorName: (NSString *) theMirrorName;
-(NSString *) str_tilename;
-(NSString *) str_mirrortilename;

@end
```

and then my .m file...

```
#import "Domino.h"

@implementation Domino

@synthesize int_leading,int_trailing, str_tilename, str_mirrortilename, int_playerid;

-(void) print     { 
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", int_leading, int_trailing);}

-(void) setTileName: (NSString *) theTileName;
{
    str_tilename=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: theTileName];
}

-(void) setMirrorName: (NSString *) theMirrorName;
{
    str_mirrortilename=[[NSString alloc] initWithString: theMirrorName];
}

-(NSString *) str_tilename
{
    return str_tilename;
}

-(NSString *) str_mirrortilename
{
    return str_mirrortilename;
}
@end
```

Finally, in my game layer...

```
Domino *d06 =[[Domino alloc] initWithSpriteFrameName:@"blank.png"];
TileName= @"0-6.png";
MirrorName= @"6-0.png";
[d06 setTileName: TileName];
[d06 setMirrorName: MirrorName];
d06.int_leading=0;
d06.int_trailing=6;
```

At this point, I add all the dominoes together into a large mutable array that tracks which ones are still available for players to pick.  The problem I'm having is that I either haven't found how to pull out the "TileName" from the mutable array, or maybe I have found it, but not understood it.

If I'm in a For loop, I would think the code should be something like

```
 NSString *temp1=[[[movableSprites objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"str_tilename"]string];
```

But this just results in the program crashing.  Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *temp1=[(Domino *)[movableSprites objectAtIndex:i] str_tilename];
```

I think using this code will solve your stuff... Check for the syntax.. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Amazing how you can stare at something for hours and overlook something so simple.  Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Its just a matter of 2 years of experience in cocos2d.. :P